# How do electric tillers compare with gas powered ones?

Tags: tools, tilling

I have 6 raised beds filled with topsoil and compost, and am looking for a tiller. They total about 200 sq.ft. I see a lot of electric tillers on the market and wonder how they perform compared to gas tillers? They seem to be very inexpensive which I like but will they do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 200 sq. feet, if you have decent soil, an electric tiller will work, but you may have to recharge halfway through. I have found that it is much less of a hassle to use a small 2 cycle gas tiller in a bed like that. They are much more powerful, never need recharging (refueling is way faster), and if something breaks, repairs are a lot cheaper. There are a lot of small engine mechanics out there.

Comment: @user19997 Did you decide what you wanted to do tiller-wise yet?

Comment: I have a small Ryobi tiller I'm going to stay with for now and forgo the battery tiller. Maybe I'll find a larger one for sale on Craig's list.

Comment: That sounds great! Gas is what I recommend.

Comment: @J.Musser hopefully advances in battery technology help make these tools hold more juice.